I have issue with ArabicShaping shaping on android
I using shapeArabicText to draw Arabic text uisng iText, and this is the code :
private fun shapeArabicText(text: String): String {
    val arabicShaping = ArabicShaping(ArabicShaping.LETTERS_SHAPE)
    var shapedText: String = arabicShaping.shape(text)

    val bid = Bidi(shapedText, Bidi.DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
    if (bid.isMixed || bid.isRightToLeft) {
        bid.reorderingMode = 0
        bid.isInverse = true
        shapedText = bid.writeReordered(Bidi.DO_MIRRORING.toInt())
    }
    return shapedText
}

The issue with this code is in case of I have multiple line , the text arrangement will be from down to top not top to down  , this is the input :
هذا النص هو مثال لنص يمكن أن يستبدل في نفس المساحة، لقد تم توليد هذا النص من مولد النص العربى، حيث يمكنك أن تولد مثل هذا النص أو العديد من النصوص الأخرى إضافة إلى زيادة عدد الحروف التى يولدها التطبيق.
this is the output
الأخرى إضافة إلى زیادة عدد الحروف التى یولدھا التطبیق.
حیث یمكنك أن تولد مثل ھذا النص أو العدید من النصوص
في نفس المساحة، لقد تم تولید ھذا النص من مولد النص العربى،
ھذا النص ھو مثال لنص یمكن أن یستبدل

Can you try with isInverse=false or just remove it?

That is not working whatever I did with this flag
